# How to enter to economics/finance sector

Tags: programming, econometrics, quantitative

Although my question is a general question, I would appreciate your suggestions or help me to find a proper "stack exchange" in order to ask my question: 
I am a Ph.D student in (Pure)Mathematics and for future I intend to find a job in Economic or finance sector,i.e, Insurance companies or other related sectors. I want to know which skills like programming and software and theoretical knowledge should I have?
Is it possible to deepen my skills during my research activity in math on one side and finance on the other side ? 
Indeed , in my opinion learning some skills are not as perfect as when we are at the real situation, so I suppose my attempts might be useless in advance?
I would be grateful if you could give me a method as a start point for my plans.

Comment: Welcome user118746! Unfortunately this is not a good question for this forum. In general Programming skills are very valuable in this business, as well as knowledge of Probability and Statistics.